# Adding fixing amount of decimal places in the middle of your formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My formula works in general but it does not put out the correct number of decimal places all the way through it.

I've tried wrapping the first C11 with the ROUND function and trying to Format the cell block but with no luck.

C11=0.0390
D11=0.0006

```
=C11&""" ± " & D11 & """ (" & C11-D11 & """ ↔ " & C11+D11 & """)"))
```

What I want the results to be: 0.0390" ± 0.0006" (0.0384" ↔ 0.0396")

What the results are actually: 0.039" ± 0.0006" (0.0384" ↔ 0.0396")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=FIXED(C11, 4) &""" ± " & FIXED(D11, 4) & """ (" 
 & FIXED(C11-D11, 4) & """ ↔ " & FIXED(C11+D11, 4) & """)"))
```